# Nonreturn to Zero-Level (NRZ-L) Digital Signal Encoding

Tags: encoding

0= high level

1= low level

as the first one in the following : enter image description here

as i searched i founded another representation which is the reverse of the above :

0= low level

1= high level

as the following :

[image: Nrz-L Digital Encoding]

as i searched i founded another representation which is the reverse of the above :

0= low level

1= high level

as the following :

[image]

so which one is correct ?! the first ? the second ?! or both ?!

Kind regards

Comment: So 1 has value up on 0 and other has value up on 1?

Comment: @camdixon yes , so which one is correct ?! both ?!

Comment: anyone can help ?!

Comment: both are correct